# Can't always set React Native breakpoints in Chrome

Tags: react-native

While debugging my React Native app in Chrome, I'm often unable to set breakpoints in the Sources tab.  When I click on a line of code to add the breakpoint, a breakpoint is added instead to the next function declaration line in my module.

This doesn't happen in all of my source modules, but often enough that it prevents me from debugging efficiently.

I'm currently using RN 0.22 but this has been happening on older versions of RN as well (e.g. RN 0.18).

Comment: I encountered the same problem. I wonder if you have solved it yet. If so, could you update your solution here?

Comment: No, still haven't solved it.

Comment: Is anybody still having this issue? I am using Expo and the React Native Debugger, and often my breakpoints don't get hit and weird things happen. I am beyond frustrated with the react native tooling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem maybe caused by babel. When use normal function and arrow function together, it happened.

Comment: I do use arrow functions.  I replaced all of them with regular function calls in one of the modules I wanted to debug.  But it didn't solve this issue.  Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Not sure where I went wrong when I initially tried this solution, but here's more detailed answer as posted on git react-native.

Replace
function someFn() {}
with
const someFn = () => {}

There can't be ANY functions in the source file you're trying to set a breakpoint in.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10729

Answer (score 5):

`"sourceMaps": "inline"` in .babelrc fixed this for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This might be the right answer, but to make it a good answer, it's a good idea to add explanations and examples of how or why this is the correct solution. I advise reading the [answer] page for more info.

Comment: didn't work for me. Put everything on one line for me

Answer (score 2):

I've only experienced this issue under the following conditions:
1) The .js file contains multiple functions, and
2) Attempting to set a breakpoint within a function that is not the last function in the .js file

So, a partial workaround is to move a function such that it is the last function in the .js file.  Or, you could assign a single function per file.  Either way, you will be able to set breakpoints.

This is far from ideal, but it's the only "solution" I've found so far.

Comment: That's wild. It's basically just not having the ability to set breakpoints.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: "only under following conditions" :) Well, aren't they an edge case

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I have a cozy solution for now :
I put the word "debugger" in the file which I want to debug.
I refresh the browser to see that it stops.
after it stops, I can add as much as breakpoints as I want and remove the "debugger" word from file

Answer (score 0):

Try this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-breakpoint-fix

just install the package and run react-breakpoint-fix from the terminal.

This fixed it for me. I'm using react-scripts@3.x

Comment: doesn't works for me. after installation prints `command not found: react-breakpoint-fix`